# How do I map a change set to a Jira issue with FishEye

Tags: mercurial, jira, atlassian-fisheye

I've managed to get Atlassian's FishEye (2.7.5) up and running and working with my Mercurial repositories. I've also got the Jira (4.4.1) integration working and when I browse to a project I see my Changesets in the "Source" panel for a project, for example:

[image]

What I don't know how to do is map changesets to issues. For example if I have a Jira issue "ABCD-2123" and a changeset "067768a5d..." in the mapped repository how do I associate them so that the changeset appears in the Activity -> Source tab for the issue? i.e.:

[image]

**Update:**

I should clarify that I know how to use Smart Commits, what I'd like to be able to do is associate a commit that didn't have an issue ID at the time of committing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand why this isn't possible. FishEye scans the commit messages looking for issue ID matches, if there's no matches then there's nothing to show in the source tab for the issue.

To make this work I'd need to alter history in the Mercurial repository using something like [`histedit`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) which is a [whole other problem area](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory).